# How to destruct a grpc message in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, grpc

I want to destruct a grpc message like this.

```
message AskOrUpdateQuestionRequest {
   int64 user_id = 1;
   int64 product_id = 2;
   core.model.QuestionProfile question = 3;
}

message QuestionProfile {
   int64 id = 1;
   Question.Status status = 2;
   Question.Type type = 3;
   string title = 4; 
}
```

I try to destruct this object? (grpc message) in kotlin

```
   val  (title) = request.question
```

However, it failed with an error.

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type QuestionModelProtos.QuestionProfile! must have a 'component1()' function

How can I make that work

Hopefully that makes sense.

**SOLVED** : @Alex Filatov 's answer helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val (title) = request.question` [compiles to](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) `val title = request.question.component1()`. Protobuf classes don't have `componentX()` methods, so you need to [add them](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

`operator fun QuestionModelProtos.QuestionProfile.component1() = this.title`